# Tensorflow - get Adam step size via callback

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to obtain the step size from Adam optimizer in TensorFlow. I already managed to log the learning rate to TensorBoard via custom callback, however I had to learn that Adam, despite being "adaptive", has a constant learning rate.

The weight update rule from Adam is given by

[image: weight_update]

In consequence, what I am looking to log is

[image: step]

where [image: alpha] denotes the constant learning rate.

While I can easily access parameters like the learning rate via `K.eval(self.model.optimizer.lr)`, how do I access the actual step size, i.e. the parameters `m_t` and `v_t`? The optimizer class offers a method [`get_updates()`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/v2.9.0/keras/optimizers/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py#L775-L782) that requires the loss and a list of parameters. The documentation does not state which parameters are needed, does anyone know? On the other hand I am not sure whether the method returns the step size of the optimizer or anything else.

Any help is greatly appreciated!